# Grouping duplicated fields with awk

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
ID|2018-04-29
ID|2018-04-29
ID|2018-04-29
ID1|2018-06-26
ID1|2018-06-26
ID1|2018-08-07
ID1|2018-08-22
```

and using awk, I want to add `$3` that groups the duplicated IDs based on `$1` and `$2` so that the output would be

```
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID1|2018-06-26|group2
ID1|2018-06-26|group2
ID1|2018-08-07|group3
ID1|2018-08-22|group4
```

I tried the following code but it does not give me the desired output. Also, I am not sure if I can apply it to a column with date in it.

```
awk -F"|" '{print $0,"group"++seen[$1,$3]}' OFS="|"
```

Any hints on how to achieve it using awk (one-liner, if possible) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the file sorted?

Comment: Thanks James. It is sorted in the above example (based on `$2`) but the original file is not sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and using awk, I want to add $3 that groups the duplicated IDs based
> on $1 and $2 so that the output would be

Using `$1` and `$2`

**If input file is sorted then:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{print $0, "group" (!a[$1,$2]++?++c:c)}' file
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID1|2018-06-26|group2
ID1|2018-06-26|group2
ID1|2018-08-07|group3
ID1|2018-08-22|group4
```

**If file not sorted then :**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{k=$1 SUBSEP $2}!(k in a){a[k]=++c}{print $0, "group" a[k]}' file
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID|2018-04-29|group1
ID1|2018-06-26|group2
ID1|2018-06-26|group2
ID1|2018-08-07|group3
ID1|2018-08-22|group4
```

Better Readable version:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        FS=OFS="|"
     }
     {
       k=$1 SUBSEP $2
     } 
     !(k in a){
        a[k]=++c
     }
     {
       print $0, "group" a[k]
     }' file
```

Comment: Hi Akshay Hegde, my actual input file was not sorted so your second code worked perfectly fine. Thank you

Comment: If say yours columns are 1 and 3 then modify variable `k = $1 SUBSEP $3`

Comment: Hi Akshay Hegde, yes, I did that and it worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: If more columns are there to group example columns 1, 3, 5 then just modify variable `k` with `SUBSEP` like `k=$1 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $5`

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v OFS="|" '!arr[$0]++{count++} {print $0,"group"count}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                    ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  OFS="|"                 ##Setting OFS to | here.
}
!arr[$0]++{               ##Checking if current line is NOT present in array then do following.
  count++                 ##Increasing count with 1 here.
}
{
  print $0,"group"count   ##Printing current line with group and count value here.
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It works on the above sample input but when I tried it on my actual file, it does not work for some reason. My original input file is not sorted and it has `ID` in `$1` and date in `$3`

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow, ok then please try like: `awk -v OFS="|" '!arr[$1,$3]++{count++} {print $0,"group"count}' Input_file` based on 1st and 3rd fields it increases count now, please check and let me know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 that version in your comment would fail because the 2nd time the key is seen the `count` will retain the most recent value it had (for some other key), not the value it had the first time the key was seen.

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow if your real input has the keys in $1 and $3 then edit your question to show sample input that looks like that, not sample input that looks like something else.

Comment: Hi  RavinderSingh13! thank you! I tried it on my unsorted input file but it did not work for me. Sorry!

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow, may be try: `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} !arr[$1,$3]++{count++} {print $0,"group"count}' Input_file` once(though we need to keep in mind what Ed has said above)?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN   {OFS = FS = "|"}

{ if ($0 != prev) {          #new item
    prev = $0                            
    print $1, $2, "group" ++g
  } 
  else {
    print $1, $2, "group" g
  }
}
```

Note that the list has to be sorted (from your example, I assume it is).
This is my first time posting answer here. Hope the code is readable for you and hope it helps.